# jQuery - stop mouseover loop

Tags: jquery, mouseover, alert

I need to stop the mouseover event if a condition is true and I don't really now how. I 've made this:

```
$('body').mouseover(function() {
    if ($('span.done').length > 0) {
        alert('done!');
    }
});
```

after the alert() is called, the mouseover should stop, and stop calling the allert.
Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at jquery .one() event handler.  Doc is [here.](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('body').on("mouseover.done",function() {
    if ($('span.done').length > 0) {
        $("body").off("mouseover.done");
        alert('done!');
    }
});
```